# How to change the description of a file in CVS?

Tags: cvs

How to change the description of a file in CVS? By description, I mean the text after the "description:" line when I issue `cvs log`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using `cvs admin -t-<new description> <filename>`

Example:

```
cvs admin -t-"Math library" math_lib.c
```